# Reponsive layout questions

Tags: html, css

I want to build this site: http://www.alsite.com.br/misskessi responsive... but i have some doubts about the responsive format.

I want to know what i need to do to images, links, texts...? i think this is with percentage, but how much?.. how i can see how much i need to resize to fit the resolution....

exemple:
 on my resolution (1600 x 900) this works fine:

```
#wrap{
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-left:-495px;
    margin-top:-359.5px;
    width:990px;
    height:719px;
    background-color: rgba(247, 8, 8, 0.2);
}
```

but on 1024x768 resolution, appears scrollbars... so i need to responsive this...

but how?

can anyone help me?

Comment: This may help: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/04/25/maintain-hierarchy-content-choreography/

Comment: Indeed, the article in the link is a good resource. Generally, though, you want to avoid using any specific pixel measurements (like "900px") **unless you're using media queries**. You've got specifically-sized margins there, so if the screen is smaller than the total number of pixels, you get a scrollbar.

Comment: Just FYI, there is a *better* trick to making a "site in a box" layout that is always centered. Or at least, it has always been better for me. Simply place a content-wrapper inside of 2 divs given specific CSS displays of `table` and `table-cell`. From there you simply need ensure the height and width of the body and height of the `div:table` and you're good to go! [Try it here!](http://jsfiddle.net/LQ6tW/) And oh yea, use of `vertical-align: middle` as well. [See example Full screen here](http://jsfiddle.net/LQ6tW/show/)

Comment: Using tables for layouts is pretty oldschool...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this time i answer on a question about responsive design the question will not get deleted ;)

There is a difference between responsive design and percentages.
If you want to go for percentages you have to to add them at every point. Currently you are having it centered on the screen but your width and height and margins are fixed (in the logical, not the css way). You would have to change them to percentual values too. To keep the image from getting to big you should check out the `max-height` / `min-height` properties (the same way for width, left etc.)

Furthermore that is not really responsive, to make you site responsive and adaptive to even very small browsers you should check out `media queries` (http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries). These two sites helped me a lot, when i had to create a responsive website in the past weeks (http://wywy.tv/howimetyourmother).

With media queries you can modify your css classes if various conditions are fullfilled, most times the width of the screen, by putting this in your css-code for example:

```
@media (max-width: 755px) {
  .content {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .header {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }   
  ...
}
```

You can extend this code quite much, maybe have a look at the css-files on my developed site to see what i did and how it affects the appearance.

Comment: Good showing, ol' chum! Right good answer!

Comment: yeah.. good answer! right... if i use `media queries`.. i have my content with `width=960px`, and my logo with `width=320px`. I need to set on the css, that my logo has a 320px/960px = 33,33% width? is that or i'm talking silly?

Comment: neither, you can do this, but you can do almost everything, you can specify that if the size of side is above some point the image has a fixed width and below it has width 100%, if you image is 320px wide you can set the point to switch to exactly that value, then your image will never be upscaled and be filling if large enough and so, even if there would be easier ways to do JUST that, but since you are asking about repsonsive design, i gave a brief explanation of that.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things to keep in mind when building responsive sites.

1. Use Media Queries to define important break points within your design. Some common break points are <320px, <480px, <768px, >768px and up.
2. Make your layout fluid. You can use a grid system if it helps - 960 Grid System, Gridset, Columnal, Golden GS, etc.
3. Images should be set at 100% with a max-width. Make use of break points as well - You can make your images change positioning in relation to your different break points. When working with mobile layouts, keep only the essential images and hide the useless (non-important) ones.
4. Make use of Max-width/height and Min-width/height. These are very helpful as it lets you define a "lowest and highest" width/height in a few little characters.
5. For mobile layouts make your columns 100% width - You basically will use one column that spans all the way down. The media query you will use for this is for anything <320px.
6. As I said above - Keep only the essential content. On your bigger layout (>768-1024+) you can use your fancy images, but under that make sure you think content first and fancy second. This is specially important for mobile layouts.
7. Keep your layout simple
8. Don't forget your viewport meta tag.

   < meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" >

Answer (score -2):

You could make the image a background-image and use "background-size: cover;", which scales it to browser size.

Comment: but.. i don't want the background full